# Disable URL Rewrite rules

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using window server 2003 sp2 and IIS 6, I have used URL rewrite for url rewriting, I am having trouble in installing URL rewritter in IIS 6 so I want to disable the rules temporarily

How can I disable URL rewriting temporarily, Is there something I need to add in web.config?
Regards

Answer (score 9):

You can disable each rule individually using the enable attribute of the rule tag.  For example,

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="myRule" enabled="false">
                    ...
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The key part is the enabled="false".  If omitted, this value defaults to true.

There is no corresponding attribute in the rules (plural) tag to toggle all rules at once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment your `<rewrite>` tag to disable IIS URL rewrite.

Comment: I tried doing it,but its still applying the rules because of which I cant open my web pages

Comment: Try to disable URL on that particular Web application using IIS Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser will still remember the rule even after you remove it. So make sure to also clear browser history, cookies, form data, etc...